# Getting ipv6 only on ubuntu server with vmware bridge connection

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, ipv6, vmware-workstation, ipv4

I have ubuntu server 12.10 on vmware.

When I have NAT network configuration I get ipv4 address (checking ifconfig eth0).

With bridged connection I get only ipv6 connection, but I need an ipv4 connection as well..

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

With a bridged connection VMware does nothing for you in regard to addressing. It should work as if the VM is connected directly to the ethernet. If your ethernet has a DHCP server and you have the VM configured to use DHCP then it should just work. If your ethernet does not have a DHCP server then you need to configure IPv4 manually.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by editing the virtual network in VMware.  Select the bridged network (should be 3 total by default) and change type of bridge "automatic" to your network card (i.e. realtek, etc...)

Then restart networking in ubuntu

sudo service network-manager restart

or via GUI, right click on icon